# Startup shortcuts screen lost.

Tags: unity, shortcuts

When I first upgraded to Trusty Tahr, there was a screen with the keyboard shortcuts.

After that, I don't see it again and don't know how to find it.

Does anyone know where it went?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the super key during 5 seconds. (My super key is the Windows key)

Comment: Thank you.  This works only when I disable the Workspaces, but at least I got to see the shortcuts.